In VS Code, how do I unfold a section of code completely?
I want to unfold a selection of code completely in Visual Studio Code. There is the "Unfold" command, but this only seems to unfold a single level of the selected code. There is also the "Unfold All" command, but this unfolds all regions in the document. Is there a way to unfold only the highlighted selection, but unfold everything inside it?

Visual Studio code does not have this functionality, but there are quite a few extensions on the VSCode marketplace that you could wrangle to get your desired result.

Put your cursor somewhere in the line containing the folded regions, and then invoke the editor.unfoldRecursively command ("Unfold Recursively" in the command palette). It's bound by default to ctrl/cmd+k,ctrl/cmd+]. You can rebind it as you wish.
